# Why "&" to run command in background does not work when the command is executed by spawnSync

Tags: node.js, shell, spawn

I am trying to execute shell script via `spawnSync` where I need to run one of commands in background but the "&" seems just to be ignored.

My code:

```
spawnSync(`echo "*** Begin" && npm run startServer & echo "*** End"`, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "inherit"],
        encoding: "utf-8",
        shell: true,
    });
```

From some reason, the command `startServer` is not executed in the background so second echo command is never executed.

Note: The script above is running as expected when I run it directly from bash.

EDIT:
A little bit of clarification:

- The command `startServer` will run forever as it is serving the server so it will never return under normal circumstances. From that reason, I need to run in background.
- Originally, I had standard shell script (see below) which was working as expected. I thought that I will be able to execute more/less same script with `spawnSync` but it behaves differently.

```
    some commands
    some commands
    npm run startServer & 
    some commands
    ....
```

Comment: What happens, if you do (for debugging) a `.... echo "*** End"; sleep 99`; Do you **then** see the second `echo`?

Comment: No, sleep does not help as command `startServer` will never end  as it is serving the server. From that reason, we need to execute it in background.

Comment: I don't expect the server to end. I'm interested in the printing of the string "End". The OP claims that this is not printed, and I could imagine this happening as a race condition between the process running `spawnSync` and the process it controls.

Comment: I tried your proposal but the second echo is not executed :/.

Comment: So at least we know for sure that it has to do with the `&` not working. As a next experiment, I would replace the command by `sh -c 'echo Begin; npm run startServer &; echo $!; echo End`, i.e. delegating this explicitly to a shell subprocess.

Comment: Ah, and - just for the safe side: You **do** see the printing of the **Begin**, do you???

Comment: Yes, the first echo and output from `startServer` are printed. `sh -c 'echo Begin; npm run startServer &; echo $!; echo End` is behaving still same. The command  `startServer` is not executed on the background.

Comment: I guess you did write the closing single quote after the word _End_ which I missed in my comment? Now it's getting strange. And you already tested, that it worked well outside Node.js, i.e. in plain bash.  So it must be somehow related to the spawnSync call. So, how about using [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options) instead of `spanSync`? I don't know any Node.js, but it seems to be simpler, and sufficient for your use.

Comment: BTW, I don't see from your code, how you collect the stdout from your _spawn_ method. Perhaps you have an error in how you pull the output out of the object returned by this method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specifics of nodeJS and spawnSync, howver you essentially want to disassociate your server command from the current shell process.

You can achieve this by prepending your npm command with `nohup`

```bash
echo "*** Begin" && nohup npm run startServer & echo "*** End"
```

Since you're attempting to run the echo End command in parallel with your npm command, it will execute the end command right after the Begin. Further, it will keep the command running even after the terminal is killed.

Comment: Th `nohup` makes sense, but does not explain to me, why the second `echo` is not executed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but `nohup` does not make the comnmand `startServer` to run on background.

Answer (score 0):

I found one alternative solution with using `spawn` for the serving server. . Not ideal as I need to break the origin script to smaller pieces.

```
spawnSync(`some command && some command`, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "inherit"],
        encoding: "utf-8",
        shell: true,
}

const serverProcess = spawn(`npm run startServer`, {
        shell: true,
}); 

spawnSync(`another command && another command`, {
        stdio: ["ignore", "pipe", "inherit"],
        encoding: "utf-8",
        shell: true,
}
```

Anyway, I would like still know why `&` is not working in `spawnSync`